# How do I output XML schema?

Tags: views, services

I have set the REST server with the Services module.

Also I've installed the Services Views module, created a new view that outputs the desired fields into XML.

That's working fine.

How can I add XML schema to that output, so the XML will look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to hook into the rest server module's formatters. This is untested but I think it'll work:

```
function MYMODULE_rest_server_response_formatters_alter(&$formatters) {
  $formatters['xml']['formatter class'] = 'MyServicesXMLFormatter';
}

...

class MyServicesXMLFormatter extends ServicesXMLFormatter {

  public function render($data) {
    // This is the default code from ServicesXMLFormatter::render(), 
    // manipulate this to add your schema and return the saved doc as normal
    $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8'); 
    $root = $doc->createElement('result'); 
    $doc->appendChild($root); 
    $this->xml_recursive($doc, $root, $data); 
    return $doc->saveXML();
  }

}
```

Comment: Clive, thank you for your answer. I've tested the code, but it's not working. This error appears: **<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to private method ServicesXMLFormatter::xml_recursive() from context 'MyServicesXMLFormatter'**

Comment: Oh, that means the person who wrote `ServicesXMLFormatter` didn't do it properly. You'll probably need to duplicate the entire `ServicesXMLFormatter` class as `MyServicesXMLFormatter`, and just make changes to the `render` method

Comment: I've just compared the both ServicesXMLFormatter. They are the same and I'm not sure what changes do I need to make in render function.

Comment: That's beyond what we can help you with here (DOMDocument is nothing to do with Drupal). If you get stuck there's always Stack Overflow, where such a question would be on topic

Comment: I've already searched about the DPMDocument with XML, but there I found only schema validators, not the structure. OK, thanks anyway. If I find the solution I'll post it here as an answer.

Comment: It's going to be something as simple as `$el = $doc->createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema', 'xs:schema'); $doc->appendChild($el);`, just have a play around with it

Answer (score 0):

Besides retrieving content as XML, do you need any other functionality provided by the Services module? If not, it might be overkill.

One simple alternative might be to write a module that implements hook_menu() to define a menu item for a wildcard path such as node/%/xml, which then, in its page callback, outputs the XML in your specified format.

```
    <?php

function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['node/%nid/xml'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_xml_view',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
  );
  return $items;
}

function mymodule_xml_view($nid) {
  drupal_set_header('Content-Type: text/xml');

  echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
  echo '<ngd:mediafile ...>';
  echo '<nid>' . $nid . '</nid>';
  // ...
  echo '</ngd:mediafile>';

  drupal_exit();
}
```

Then, after enabling the new module, you can retrieve XML content by simply fetching, for example, [URL http://example.com/node/42/xml .](http://example.com/node/42/xml)